# Adapt/disable jQuery code for mobile view in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I have **sticky header** in my website. When I tried to optimize my header for mobile, everything was ok but, when it became **sticky** it resize him or something like that so my **navigation** is not visible. I want to know is there any way to change jQuery code in css so my header doesn't resize when it became **sticky**.

**Here is my code example:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JKXYpa

**Note:** If you want to see where is the problem, just resize your browser on width < 480px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following CSS should work for you.  You're doing a few things that are causing problems.  Most importantly, your #wrapper declaration contradicts itself.  You have declared a min-width that is larger than your max-width.  min-width has to be less than max-width.

I've made a few other small adjustments including reducing the header font sizes in your media query for small screen sizes, to make the nav fit.  Otherwise, it will wrap below the blue container.

```
    *{
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }

    /* Header */
    #header {
        transform: translateZ(10px);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-color:#3cb5f9;
        width: 100%;
        height: 80px;
        top:200;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 999;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        border-bottom:1px solid white;
    }
    #header nav {
        display: inline-block;
        float:right;
        line-height:80px;
    }
    #header nav a {
        margin-left: 25px;
        color: #fafafa;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 18px;
        text-decoration:none;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
        -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s;
        transition: all 0.5s;
    }
    #header nav a:hover {
        color: black; 
    }
    #header img {
        line-height:80px;
        margin-top:14px;
        display:block;
        float:left;
        height:51px;
    }

    .clearfix{
        display: block;
        width:70%;
        clear:both;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    /*Mobile part*/
    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

        #header {
            width: 100vw;
            float:none;
        }

        p{ 
            font-size: 0.5em;
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar{
            display:none;
        } 

        #header nav{
            float:right;
        }
        #header nav {
            display: inline-block;
            float:center;
            line-height:80px;
        }
        #header nav a {
            font-size: 12px;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
        #header nav a:hover {
            color: black; 
        }
        #header .clearfix {
            width: 95%;
        }
    }

    /* Other */

    #main{
        width: 100%;
        color:#3cb5f9;
        margin: 0 auto; 
    }

    .container{
        width:70%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #wrapper {
        max-width:1240px;
        height:2000px;
        color:#3cb5f9;
        margin: 0 auto; 
    }

    .home{
        width:100vw;
        height:600px;
        clear:both; 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I just don't know why should wrapper's `max-width` should be 1240px ? Is is default or what ?

Comment: You can set the default widths of your layouts to whatever you want.  There is no default.  There's a lot of debate online about what's best and about whether or not you should set a fixed-width at all.  If you want more information about that try looking up something like 'fixed versus fluid web layout'.

Comment: Ok. Thank you a lot :)